# How are access times, modified times, encodings and filenames stored in files on NTFS and EXT3/4?

Tags: file, filesystems, ntfs, ext3, ext4

For academic and task related purposes I need to know how is file related data associated within files on NTFS and EXT. How does the operating system know file's name? How do editors know in which encoding to treat the file contents?

Are these details stored on a separate information location on the NTFS/EXT or are they included within the file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On NTFS such information is stored not in the file itself but in the master file table (MFT).

You are asking many questions. I suggest you read up on the subject. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) is the short version, and [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625301) is everything in full detail.

Comment: But aren't all those details carried along when you, say, download a file from the Internet?

Comment: No. As an example consider Alternate Data Streams (ADS), a specific feature of NTFS. Common file transfer protocols (SMB, HTTP) do not transfer ADS information. Whenever a file is transferred to another system, such information is left behind.